# How to return initial value of a cell formula's IF function

Tags: excel

I am attempting to build out an IF statement that contains a long index/match formula in it. I want the IF statement to return the initial value that the index/match statement finds if the logical test is true. Is there a way to go about that without copying and pasting the formula?

```
=IF(
    INDEX(
        '2019'!$E$5:$BU$133,
        MATCH(
            Sheet1!$C$2&Sheet1!$C$3&$D8, 
            INDEX(
                '2019'!$B$5:$B$133&'2019'!$C$5:$C$133&'2019'!$D$5:$D$133,
                0
            ),
            0
        ),
        MATCH( Sheet1!E$7,'2019'!$E$3:$BU$3,0 )
    ) > '2019'!E6, 
    value_if_true,
    value_if_false
)
```

So, if the `index/match > 2019!E6`, i want to return the index/match value. Thanks for the help!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the formula exactly. Allthough there is no such thing as intermediate variables, there might just be a smarter way of writing your formula. Some sample data and desired output could help us help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

Consider defining the index/match portion of your formula in a separate cell:

```
=INDEX('2019'!$E$5:$BU$133, MATCH(Sheet1!$C$2 ...
```

You can then refer to it in your formula. So, if the above index/match was placed in cell A1, you can refer to it in this way:

```
=IF(A1 > '2019'!E6, A1, ...
```

To reduce clutter, such intermediate formulas (like index/match in your case) can be placed in hidden columns.

Comment: I wish Excel would allow for multi-statement formulas with intermediate variables :(